# Python Quickstart ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google_auth_oauthlib'

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets

I set up a venv for my project and ran pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib to get the Google packages (after activating the venv).

When I attempt to run the [Python Quickstart code](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python) (which I copy/pasted into my VScode project) I get the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google_auth_oauthlib'. I ran pip list and verified that version 0.4.2 is installed.

[image: pip list snapshot]

My setup:
MacOS 10.15.07
VScode 1.53.2
venv Python 3.7.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be sure, activate the virtual environment in the shell you will use to run the quickstart and run `pip freeze`. Additionally make sure your the python you are using is the one in the venv. You can do `which python`

Comment: I activated the virtual environment and ran pip freeze, but the problem persists. Running which python validates that the virtual environment has been activated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using pip3 install instead? This is what fixed it for me.